# How to turn off automatic pre-rendering of pages in Google chrome

Tags: 11.04

I get normally pissed off when chrome automatically renders google search results of addresses before I even finish typing. How do I turn this off in Chrome 13?

Comment: So I can't ask a question about using third party applications installed on a Ubuntu rig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click the little wrench icon top right

choose *preferences*

under the search section de-select *Enable instant...*